# PageViewController scrolling through views no default view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

http://pastebin.com/hTvFg06m
It used to work up until I changed the first view that initiates, which works by day.

```
    private func newColoredViewController (name: String) -> UIViewController{
    let today = getDay()
    return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) .
    instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "\(today)ViewController")
```

It doesn't work with (today)ViewController, it used to work with (name)ViewController.

How can I make it scroll again with different initiate?

Comment: output of `print("\(today)ViewController")` is?

Comment: @Mr.Bista it's Thursday just like I wanted it to be, and it loads the fifth view like it's supposed to. But scrolling doesn't work.

Comment: He's not acting as a part of an array he's presented alone.

Comment: Can you show a gif image of your page view controller swiping?